# Anonymous function throws an error in PHP 5.4

Tags: php, lambda, anonymous-function, parse-error, array-map

Using anonymous function in PHP 5.4 throws a parse error. The code works fine on all servers except one. It uses PHP 5.4.38 on CentOS.

Here is a short error copy:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ‘)’ in path/to/file.php on line 33
```

And here is how the function look like:

```
31.     public static function list_to_array($list, $delimiter = ","){
32.         $array = explode($delimiter, trim($list));
33.         $array = array_map(function($string) {
34.             return htmlspecialchars(trim($string), ENT_QUOTES);
35.         }, $array);
36.         return $array;
37      }
```

If you look at this code everything seems to be ok and should work without problems in PHP 5.3+, but for some reason it does not.
I've serched on google for days and could not find a solution.

Is there something that I've missed. May be the anonymous functions disabled by server or something like that?

Comment: How did you get your php version string? Did you use `<?php phpinfo() ?>`?

Comment: @Victory Yes. Using this PHP function.

Comment: There might still be two different versions configured (handlers can change on a per-directory basis). Comment out the three lines right there, and test with `die(PHP_VERSION);` directly.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error: http://3v4l.org/G3V2u Please make sure you did this: 1. Restart whatever isn't working 2. quick google search 3. Come back here! Is this file `file.php` ?